# How to remove first line from a text file while appending a column to its own list?

Tags: python

I am trying to append a whole column to a new list, but I need to remove the header from the column so it is just numbers. I am trying to append the size column to a list if its value is greater than 12. I then want to print the length or number of values in the list. I am currently stuck, but I tried to put together previous code. How can I remove the size header so it is just numbers?

```
diameter =[]
file = open('poles.txt', 'r')
for i in file:
 if int(i[3].strip('')) > 12:
   diameter.append(int(i.strip('\n')))
file.close()
print(len(diameters))
```

```
NAME TYPE ID SIZE
TC   N    1  10
DB   P    2  12
TC   N    3  13
DB   P    4  11
TC   P    5  15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the first line by using a slice. e.g.

```
file = open('poles.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
for i in lines[1:]:
```

It is also better to use with when opening a file. e.g.

```
with open('poles.txt', 'r') as FH:
    lines = FH.readlines()
```

That way you dont have to worry about closing the file

You can then remove the double spaces with `join` and then break the line up into sections using `split`

```
diameter
with open('poles.txt', 'r') as FH:
lines = FH.readlines()
for line in lines[1:]:
    line_without_mutliple_spaces = " ".join(line.split())
    columns = line_without_mutliple_spaces.split(' ')
    if int(columns[3]) > 12:
        diameter.append(line.strip())
print(len(diameter))
```